# Add a badge to UIButtonitem with MIBadgeButton-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add a badge to my UIBarButtonItem and for that I have found a this github :

[MIBadgeButton-Swift](https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift)

but I don't know how to use it.

This is my code which makes my custom UIBarButtonItem:

```
let shopingCartBTN = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
shopingCartBTN.setImage(UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shopingCartBTN.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon")
shopingCartBTN.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)//Just increase the width of button
shopingCartBTN.setTitle("5", forState: .Normal)
shopingCartBTN.addTarget(self, action: "", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shopingCartBTN)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

How could I use the MIBadgeButton-Swift to make a badge for my UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once.

```
//Property
    var cartBarbuttonItem:MIBadgeButton?

self.cartBarbuttonItem = MIBadgeButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 5, 40, 44))
self.cartBarbuttonItem?.initWithFrame(frame: CGRectMake(40, 5, 40, 44), withBadgeString: "0", withBadgeInsets:  UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 2, 0, 15))
self.cartBarbuttonItem?.setImage(UIImage(named: "test"), forState: .Normal)
self.cartBarbuttonItem?.setImage(UIImage(named: "test"), forState: .Selected)
self.cartBarbuttonItem?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("loadCart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem = self.cartBarbuttonItem
```

Comment: I just edited the answer.Let me know if u have any queries

Answer (score 5):

Here is two example with custom view and from storyboard

From storyboard by setting custom class :

[image]

### CODE

```
@IBOutlet var btnRightBadge: MIBadgeButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Custom
    let badgeButton : MIBadgeButton = MIBadgeButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    badgeButton.setTitle("T1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    badgeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    badgeButton.badgeString = "1";
    let barButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: badgeButton)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    //From Storyboard
    btnRightBadge.badgeString = "5"
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

You can also use [ENMBadgedBarButtonItem-Swift](https://github.com/enmiller/ENMBadgedBarButtonItem-Swift)